# intro.js does not understand elements with the transform property

Tags: css, user-interface, intro.js

I'm trying to apply a step intro for the element in an upright position (turned over by the **rotate property**) and nothing happens.

How to fix it?

**more than 10 steps**

```
.chat-reveal {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9D9E9F;
    background-color: #313335;
    moz-transform-origin: 100% 0px;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0px;
    transform-origin: 100% 0px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.introjs-fixParent {
    z-index: auto !important;
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

[image]